# Display AppIcon and appname in Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, drawable

I am currently working with an application that retrieves the list of current running applications . I want to show the name of the current running applications preceded by each application Icon . The following code show the appname and drawable object of application icons.

```
    manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    pm = getPackageManager();
    lstRunning = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_running);

    List<RunningTaskInfo> appsRunning =  manager.getRunningTasks(30);//running tasks 
    String[] runningApp = new String[appsRunning.size()];
    Drawable[] icons = new Drawable[appsRunning.size()];
    int j = 0;
    for (RunningTaskInfo r: appsRunning) {

        try {
            info = pm.getApplicationInfo(r.baseActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runningApp[j] = pm.getApplicationLabel(info).toString();
        icons[j]=pm.getApplicationIcon(info);
```

How will I display the drawable object and name of the app in each row of the list ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom ListView adapter that provides a custom layout with an ImageView and a TextView.

[See here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spannable in a listView this will let you have drawables in each row.

or create your own listview that has ImageView and TextView in each row!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to create a Custom ListView with each row containing application image and application name. This link [custom ListView with image and text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) provides an easy and handsome way of doing so. You can easily customize the layout of the ListView to make its looks and feel better. I hope this helps.